# To infinitive it preposition

Tags: prepositional-phrases, to-infinitive

How to know that 'to' is infinitive particle or preposition? Which one is correct?

1. Don't try to be smart.
2. Don't try to being smart.(is to a preposition?)
3. Stop trying(is trying a gerund here?) to be smart.
4. Stop trying to being smart.(is to a preposition?)

Please give reasons also.

Answer (score 1):

The verb *try* can take a "to"-infinitive clause, or a noun clause. It cannot take a prepositional phrase introduced by "to".

This means that your 2 and 4 are not grammatical; your 1 and 3 are: *try* (whether a base form after *don't* or a gerund after *stop*) can take the clause *to be smart*.

Note that this is a property of *try*. " ... to being" is not necessarily ungrammatical, if it is in a context that can take a prepositional phrase with "to", eg *He is half-way to being smart*: "half-way" **can** take a complement (prepositional phrase) with "to".

Comment: Can we say Stop trying being smart. Stop try being smart

Comment: _Try being smart!_ is fine; so the same with other parts of the verb _try_ (eg _He tried being smart_). I find _Stop trying being smart_ awkward, because of the two "-ing" words following one another, but it's grammatical as far as I can see. _Stop_ cannot be followed by a base form, so _Stop try_ is not grammatical, whatever follows it.

Answer (score 0):

Examples 2 and 4 are not grammatical, and so can't be analyzed.

In example 1, "to be" is the to-infinitive; "to" is not a preposition.

For example 3, "trying" is a gerund-participle acting as the head of the clause "trying to be smart." That clause is the complement of "stop". The function of "to be" is the same as in example 1.

Answer (score 0):

> How to know that 'to' is infinitive particle or preposition?

In an infinitive, the X in *to X* will be a verb.  If it's a preposition, X will be a noun.

Nouns often have articles or other determiners in front of them, if one of these exists for X, *to* then has to be a preposition.

> I walked to the park - *the* is an article and that only appears in front of nouns.

One thing you can do with verbs here that you can't do with nouns is put an adverb like *definitely* in between *to* and *X*.

> I walked to the park - I walked to definitely the park (doesn't work)
>
> I wanted to go - I wanted to definitely go (work).

Also, the only form of a verb that can go after *to* is the plain form.  The *-ing* or past/past-participle forms can't have *to* in front of it and make an infinitive.

> To walk - might be an infinitive
>
> To walked, to walking - never an infinitive, generally wrong.

Perfect infinitives with *to have X'ed* are OK; progressive/continuous with *to be X'ing* is also OK.  But *to X'ed* or *to X'ing* is not OK.

So 1 and 3 are correct.